# SSG is not creating in Next.js 13.4

Tags: next.js, next.js13, static-site-generation

In Nextjs 13.4 I am haveing a page portfolio inside this page there is a dynamic page [id]
in portfolio page, icons and title of porfolio is shown, clicking in a single portfolio it will go to portfolio/[id].
all the porfolios are stored in a array of objec named portFolioData in data.js folder

the problem is static html file building for the portfolio page but not for the id pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjDPu.png)

this is the portfolio page

```
import React from 'react'

import portfolioData from '@/app/data'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { syne } from '@/components/util/fonts'


const getPortFolios = () => {
  return portfolioData
};

const Page = () => {
  const portfolios = getPortFolios();
  return (
    <div className='w-full pt-[40px] pb-[115px] sm:pt-[60px] sm:pb-[180px] lg:pt-[90px] lg:pb-[235px]'>
      <div className='mx-auto lg:w-[1180px] grid justify-center gap-[15px] sm:gap-[21px] grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3'>
        {portfolios?.map((item, index) => (
          < Link key={index} href={`portfolio/${item?.id}`} >
                  <img src={item.icon} alt={item.title} className='w-full h-full object-cover rounded-t-[10px]' />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}
export default Page
```

and I this is portfolio[id]

```
export function generateStaticParams() {
  return portfolioData.map((portfolio) => ({
    id: portfolio.id.toString(),
  }));
}


const Page =  ({ params }) => {
  const portFolioId = params.id;
  const portfolio = portfolioData.find(portfolio => portfolio.id === portFolioId);
  const swiperArrowStyles = "top-0 w-[126px] bg-[#b4b6b733] h-full flex justify-center items-center absolute z-[2] cursor-pointer";
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are seeing?

Comment: @RobinThomas thanks for your approach to help me, I have fixed the problem, Actually, the SSG was not created due to I used 'use client'.